# Catching errors on plugin initialization wth QUnit

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, qunit

I'm using the following format for creating plugins.

```
$(function () {
  function PluginName() { 
    /* some more code here */ 
  }

  $.extend(PluginName.prototype, {
    _attachPlugin: function (target, options, value) {
      target = $(target);

      if (target.hasClass(this.shortenerClass)) {
        return;
      }

      var instance = {
        options: $.extend({}, this._defaults)
      };

      if (typeof instance.options.requiredOption === 'undefined') {
        throw 'You need required option!';
      }
    },
  });

  var getters = [/* some getters */];

  function isNotChained(method, otherArgs) {
    if (method === 'option' && (otherArgs.length === 0 ||
        (otherArgs.length === 1 && typeof otherArgs[0] === 'string'))) {
      return true;
    }
    return $.inArray(method, getters) > -1;
  }

  $.fn.pluginname = function (options) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

    if (isNotChained(options, args)) {
      return plugin['_' + options + 'Plugin'].apply(plugin, [this[0]].concat(args));
    }

    return this.each(function () {
      if (typeof options === 'string') {
        if (!plugin['_' + options + 'Plugin']) {
          throw 'Unknown method: ' + options;
        }
        plugin['_' + options + 'Plugin'].apply(plugin, [this].concat(args));
      } else {
        plugin._attachPlugin(this, options || {});
      }
    });
  };

  var plugin = $.pluginname = new PluginName();
})(jQuery);
```

When I pass in my options object, I want to make sure a certain option is there. If not, throw an error from the _attachPlugin method. The error is being thrown however I am unable to get QUnit to assert that the error was thrown. Currently my test looks like this:

```
test('Init error', function () {
  throws($('#selector').pluginname(), 'Throws error when missing required option.')
});
```

I thought I could test for the error by writing the test like so:

```
test('Init error', function () {
  throws($.urlshortener._attachPlugin($('#selector')[0]), 'Throws an error');
});
```

Either way I write it, both tests are dying on that error being thrown from _attachPlugin which is QUnit is not catching.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the "throws" assertion passing a function result as the block instead of passing a function object to be called, that's why the exception is not being caught.

Instead of:

```
test('Init error', function () {
  throws($('#selector').pluginname(), 'Throws error when missing required option.')
});
```

You should define your test as:

```
test('Init error', function () {
  throws(function() { $('#selector').pluginname() }, 'Throws error when missing required option.')
});
```

This way QUnit will call the function object and manage the excpetions.

I put a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/hhk6u/9/

**Additional notes about jQuery plugins:** note in the example that I've changed the first line of your plugin code from:

```
$(function () {
```

to:

```
;(function ($) {
```

this way avoids the plugin to start automatically, and it is usually a good practice.